# Why doesn't the while loop contribute O(n) to the total time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I got this problem from [Interview Bit](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/amortized2/)

**Problem**

```
int j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
        j++;
    }
}
```

**Question**

The total number of comparisons that the while loop does is about n (probably less than or equal to n depending on `arr`). The loop runs n times. Shouldn't the time complexity be O(n^2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the conditions in the `while` loop is `while j < n`. Meaning worst case, the code will only ever loop in the `while` loop `n` times regardless of how many loops the outer `for` loop does (`j` starts at zero and only increases, never resets to zero or decreases). Since the the `for` loop also loops `n` times, your `big-O` is `O(n+n) => O(n)`

NOTE: You can safely ignore the other condition `arr[i] < arr[j]`, since we're just considering what the runtime would be in the worst-case.

Answer (score 3):

This code looks like it was purposefully designed to be misleading. The `while` loop only runs once from `0` to `n`, and does not reset for every iteration of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Re: "The `while` loop only runs once from `0` to `n`": Well, *at most* once. It's also quite possible for `j` to never reach `n`. I'm not sure if the code was purposefully designed to be misleading; it's hard to tell at a glance what it's designed to do, but there may not be a much clearer way to do whatever-that-is.

Comment: Addendum: I believe it finds the least element in the array (or the first least element if there's a tie) . . . which incidentally means that the `j < n` part isn't actually needed (I guess it's just an extra safety-check before accessing `arr[j]`. So, yeah, there's a clearer way to write this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to count the total number of times the statements in the innermost loop get executed.

The nested `while` loop does not contribute to the complexity because it goes through the values between `0` to `n-1` only once, even though the steps through these values may be distributed among different iterations of the outer loop.

The innermost "payload" of the loop, i.e. `arr[i] < arr[j]` and `j++`, will execute at most `n` times, because incrementing `j` is a "one-way street": its value is never reset back to zero, so once `j` reaches `n`, the body of the loop no longer executes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the inner loop is not dependent on 'i' ,so it will run maximum n times if 'i' goes from 0 to n-1.

The complexity would be O(n^2) if before while loop 'j' was initialised by 0, then in worst case for each 'i' while loop will execute 1+2+3+.......n-2 + n-1 times= O(n^2) when array elements are in descending order.

Comment: Note that value of j is not reset after each iteration, if j reaches n, it will do it only once. The complexity won't go above O(n).

Comment: Yes it is correct and that is what is written above that complexity would be O(n^2) "**IF**" 'j' were to be initialised before while loop....